# Intellij plugin development "the selected directory is not a valid home for intellij platform plugin sdk"

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm following [these](http://bjorn.tipling.com/how-to-make-an-intellij-idea-plugin-in-30-minutes) guidelines on how to develop Intellij plugin.

So I

1. Open project settings.
2. Project SDK --> New
3. Choose the community edition path I just downloaded

Expected the directory is selected fine.

Actual: I get the error message:

**"the selected directory is not a valid home for intellij platform plugin sdk"**

See screenshot:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Intellij platform plugin sdk home` should be your installed or builded IntelliJ, not sources. You can add that `intellij-community` folder as sources to your IntelliJ SDK later or not at all.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Intellij installed directory

1. C:\ProgramFiles\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4
2. Select plugin folder
3. Create a directory (eg: scala)
4. Copy the scala lib folder
5. Restart the intellij

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to [download](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download) a newer IDEA version (Community Edition) and after the installation, everything worked fine.

This is the official and updated [link](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/setting_up_environment.html) for setting up your plugin development environment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after trying many ways and nothing helped, uninstall IntelliJ IDE and reinstall it. This error has been resolved.
I think the error exists because I installed IntelliJ IDE before installing the SDK.
Note: I use IntelliJ IDE 2023.2.5 Community and downloaded JDK 21 for window.